# Stone not spawning at correct place after player respawns

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the player reSpawns I want the stones(which can be moved by the player), to go to their original spot. This is not working for me. Instead, the stone spawn on other nearby locations and sometimes off the map. All stones are tagged stone.

I have tried reversing the Vectors and reversing the signs on the subtraction and such.

This is the player script.

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerControll : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public bool isTouchingGround = false;

        public GameObject locater1;

        public GameObject locater2;

        public GameObject currentCheckPoint;

        public GameObject playerPrefab;

        public Rigidbody2D myRigidBody;

        public GameObject GameMaster;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {

            isTouchingGround = false;
           GameObject MyGameMaster= Instantiate(GameMaster, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            GameMaster = MyGameMaster;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKey("a"))
            {
                transform.Translate(-0.1f, 0, 0);

            }


            if (Input.GetKey("d"))
            {
                transform.Translate(0.1f, 0, 0);
            }

            if ((Input.GetKey("w") || Input.GetKey("space")) && isTouchingGround == true)
            {
                myRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 130f));
            }

            if (locater1.transform.position.y <= locater2.transform.position.y)
            {
                ReSpawn();

            }
        }

        private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Platform" || collision.gameObject.tag == "Stone")
            {
                isTouchingGround = true;
            }
        }

        private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
        {
            if ((collision.gameObject.tag == "Platform" || collision.gameObject.tag == "Stone") && locater2.transform.position.y > collision.transform.position.y) 
            {
                isTouchingGround = false;
            }

        }


        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.tag == "CheckPoint")
            {
                currentCheckPoint = collision.gameObject;
            }


            if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Radiation")
            {
                ReSpawn();
            }
        }

        public void ReSpawn()
        {
            GameMaster.gameObject.GetComponent<ReverToOriginalPositions>().RevertToOrignalPosition();
            GameObject currentPlayer=Instantiate(playerPrefab, currentCheckPoint.transform.position, currentCheckPoint.transform.rotation);
            currentPlayer.GetComponent<PlayerControll>().isTouchingGround = false;

            Destroy(this.gameObject);







        }


    }
```

This is the RememberPositions script. This belongs to every stone to remember the position is has during the start.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RememberPositions : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float StartXPosition;
    public float StartYPosition;

    float StartRotation;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartXPosition = transform.position.x;
        StartYPosition = transform.position.y;
        StartRotation = transform.rotation.z;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

this is the RevertToOriginalPosition Script. This reverts the stones to their original positions. This is in the GameMaster/MasterControll.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ReverToOriginalPositions : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] allStones;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        allStones = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Stone");



    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void RevertToOrignalPosition()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allStones.Length; i++)
        {
            allStones[i].gameObject.transform.Translate((new Vector3((allStones[i].gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x- allStones[i].gameObject.GetComponent<RememberPositions>().StartXPosition) , (allStones[i].gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y- allStones[i].gameObject.GetComponent<RememberPositions>().StartYPosition), 0)));
            allStones[i].gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, 0, -allStones[i].gameObject.transform.rotation.z);
        }




    }
}
```

This is the Store reciever Script. This is for another game mechanic called an Activator. This is not that important but I am including it anyway.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StoreReciever : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject reciever;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

   void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        reciever.gameObject.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().enabled = true;
    }

     void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        reciever.gameObject.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

No error messages at all. Just Stones reSpawning in locations they are not supposed to. Thank You for helping.

Comment: Couldn't you just save and restore `transform.position` and `transform.rotation`?

Comment: Thank You so much. I wasn't aware that you could change the transform.position component. I thought you couldn't change it because I wasn't able to change transform.position.x. Thank you for helping. It is working smoothly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make some fields/properties they dont even have to be private static readonly

```
public static readonly Vector3 StartPos = new Vector3(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
public static readonly Vector3 StartRot_In_EulerAngles = new Vector3(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
```

Then you can do something like this in a method:

```
public static void ResetMyStones()
{
   var allStones = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Stone");
   foreach(var stone in allStones)
   {
      stone.transform.position = StartPos;
      stone.transform.eulerAngles = StartRot_In_EulerAngles;
   }
}
```

***About Euler Angle:***

Why Euler Angle? - because for rotations Unity uses so called *Quaternions*, so [Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock#/media/File:Gimbal_3_axes_rotation.gif) will not happen, but the bad thing about this is that you cannot really set x y z component individually without deep understanding of Quaternions, however if you just wanna set and get a current rotation Euler Angle is perfect, because you can use the traditional x,y,z components for setting the value.

***Additional Notes:***

Your code is kinda long and not well structured, like `ReverToOriginalPositions` should be a method and not a component, also not evrything has to be a derived from monobehaviour.

Also remove the unused `Update` methods, they have a small overhead if its in a script but not used(Usually its immeasurable but in bigger project it can effect performance :)), and maybe if your game is structured that way you could store all your current stones in a GameManager class list so you dont need to call `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Stone");`